# why gitbook build will difference in win/linux

Tags: linux, windows, github, gitbook

Why is there a .md file in the subdirectory of _book created by gitbook build under windows? Under Linux, it is a pure html file.

[Linux gitbook build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aecWJ.png)

[Windows gitbook build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gemHJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

i know https://github.com/honkit/honkit/issues/146
I love him
I love him
I love him

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).